# Logical OR seems to act like conditional OR

Tags: c#

I'm somewhat unclear about the conditional vs. logical || oprators. Well, looking at what I just wrote, let me restate that: My code does not do what it supposed to do based on the differences between conditional and logical OR.

I have text box as date field that has its text property set to "mm/yyyy" by default. My validator evaluates true for this condition and for a empty value (as with two quotations /""/ marks) as well. So after all this I'm checking the value with this:

```
if (tbEndDateMo.Text != "mm/yyyy" | tbEndDateMo.Text != "" | tbEndDateMo.Text != string.Empty)
```

When the value is "mm/yyyy", it passes inside the IF and same when value is blank. Looking at this [Microsoft reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx), I understand the difference and I thought I wrote code based on this - but it does not work the way I want it to. If the text box evaluates to the "mm/yyyy" or blank (or empty) skip the IF. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Risho

Comment: You sound like you want &, not |

Comment: `|`, in this context, is not a bitwise OR, it's simply a non-short circuiting OR.  There is no reason, given your code, to avoid short circuiting.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Well, probably `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: Also note that comparing to string.Empty *and* "" is repetitive, redundant, and repetitive.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: So what if someone hits the space bar (accidently) and post the page? (I should be using Trim() - but that's anohter topic)

Comment: You answered your own question. If a space is also invalid, make it so that the program detects it. You can trim it as you suggested, which would make the comparison to string.Empty kick in, or you can update to use `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(input)`, which would handle nulls, empties, and whitespace strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You condition is incorrect - there is **100% chance**, that `tbEndDateMo.Text` is not equal to `"mm/yyy"` **or** to empty string at the same time!

You should check that:

```
if (tbEndDateMo.Text != "mm/yyyy" && tbEndDateMo.Text != "" && tbEndDateMo.Text != string.Empty)
```

However, you should consider using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method instead of `== string.Empty`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEndDateMo.Text) && tbEndDateMo.Text != "mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: IIRC, the TextBox never returns `null` from ::Text property, but indeed there's a big chance the author doesn't know that method :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the flow of your program has been pointed out. I've noticed you're claiming that the Logical OR seems to act like the conditional or. If you read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you'll see it only performs a logical or if the types are integral. Are you can see, they are boolean, and thus it computes the conditional OR :)

Comment: So, what's the proper or most commonly used method to this? It has been haunting for a while. I like @MarcinJuraszek solution, but I can't believe this would not be a common situation.

Comment: Well.. you were using the wrong operators, so @MarginJuraszek was correct in what he wrote. You simply wrote the wrong code. There is no common work around.. just correct the code :)

Comment: I did not mean workaround literarly, but is that how you would do it?

Comment: Yep. You have to structure your conditions so they are logically correct. For this purpose. @MarcinJuraszek was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a fault in your perceived logic. Examine this:

let tbEndDateMo.Text be equal to "" and let's reduce the expression

```
tbEndDateMo.Text != "mm/yyyy" | tbEndDateMo.Text != "" | tbEndDateMo.Text != string.Empty
"" != "mm/yyyy" | "" != "" | "" != string.Empty
true | false | false
true
```

Most probably you wanted:

```
tbEndDateMo.Text != "mm/yyyy" && tbEndDateMo.Text != "" && tbEndDateMo.Text != string.Empty
```

<strike>Also, remember that there's no "logic" and "conditional" OR/ANDs. Those are called "bitwise" and "logic"</strike>*). The **only difference** between them is very subtle. It is that the || and && does not evaluate subexpressions when not needed, whereas the | and & always evaluate. Therefore:

```
MyClass x = null; // intentional

if( x != null && x.Field > 8)  // will NOT throw
        ...

if( x != null & x.Field > 8)  // WILL throw NullReferenceException
        ...
```

*) ok, maybe I'm used to old nomenclature, anyways, the rest what I wrote is valid.